# How Angular JS UI-Router changes url in navigation bar without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am learning Angular JS [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I was wondering **How [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) manages to change url in navigation bar without reloading entire page?**.

I have tried reading [this](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/) blog and some stackoverflow questions, but couldn't find any proper explaination. Can some one explain properly?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Comment: This link is useful but it doesn't give any explanation about `ui-router`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on a simple fact that we can use hyperlinks(`<a>` tags) to jump to certain sections in a document and bring focus to that section. But if your  `href` attribute points to `IDs` that do not exist in your page, then the browser will not do anything but change the hash part in the URL.

In modern browsers, everytime, the hash part changes in the URL, a `hashchange` event will be fired. ui-router or any router can actually listen for this event, get the hash part and use the config to update the view section accordingly.

This works well as long as you trigger a state change by clicking on some link but there are cases where you change the state using methods like `$state.go()` or `$location.path()`. In this case, we need to resort to HTML5's History API. There's a [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) method that allows us to change the URL in the address bar without causing the browser to load that resource.

Comment: Yes that's true and credible also, but what happens when i use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`? In this scenario it does'n use hash tag to change URL.

Comment: if you set `html5Mode` to true, then they resort to using HTML5's History API where they can change the URL in the address bar without triggering a full page refresh in the browser. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)